# Change barButtonSystemItem after tapping

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem, rightbarbuttonitem

I have a bar button in the right side of the screen, it's `barButtonSystemItem: .edit` and it's used to put `tableView` in the editing mode. I want when, user tap on it, it change to `barButtonSystemItem: .done` and it close `tableview` from editing mode. 
Just to be clear, every time that barButton is clicked, the type of it should be change from edit to done.

Here is my code, but it always stay with edit, and not changing to done

```
fileprivate func addBarButton() {
    if tableView.isEditing {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(editButtonAction))
    } else {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .edit, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonAction))
    }
}


@objc func editButtonAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    tableView.isEditing = !tableView.isEditing
}



@objc func doneButtonAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    tableView.isEditing = !tableView.isEditing
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addBarButton()
    tableView?.isEditing = true
}
```

Comment: “but it always stay with edit,” Sure, because you don’t change it. Your editButtonAction never changes the button. So it doesn’t change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the bodies of methods `editButtonAction` and `editButtonAction` you only change the `tableView` editing state by doing `tableView.isEditing = !tableView.isEditing`. This action does nothing to `navigationItem` at all.

I'd recommend you to refactor the code a bit by renaming `addBarButton` into `updateBarButton` and call it every time when the `table` editing state changes and additionally from `viewDidLoad` as you do now. So your code would become something like this:

```swift
  fileprivate func updateBarButton() {
    if tableView.isEditing {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(editButtonAction))
    } else {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .edit, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonAction))
    }
}


@objc func editButtonAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    tableView.isEditing = !tableView.isEditing
    updateBarButton() // Note the additional call of the update method
}

@objc func doneButtonAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    tableView.isEditing = !tableView.isEditing
    updateBarButton() // Note the additional call of the update method
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView?.isEditing = true
    updateBarButton() // Note that we call this method after changing the table view state so that it will have the most recent value
}
```